# pytorch squeeze function doesn't do anything

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to squeeze the y tensor to be able to calculate the loss (since it is a one-hot encoding). However, the squeeze function does not seem to be doing anything. I am verifying this by printing the shapes. This is my code snippet:

```
    def train_error_and_loss(self):
        self.model.eval()
        #train_acc = 0
        loss = 0
        cTC = 0
        cP = []
        for x, y in self.trainloaderfull:
            x, y = x.to(self.device), y.to(self.device)
            output = self.model(x)
            #output_arg = np.argmax(output.detach().numpy(),axis=1)
            #output_arg = torch.from_numpy(output_arg)
            #train_acc += (torch.sum(torch.argmax(output, dim=1) == y)).item()
            print(y.squeeze(1).shape, output.squeeze(1).shape)
            print(y.shape, output.shape)
            loss += self.loss(output, y.squeeze(1))
            
            cm = confusion_matrix(y, torch.argmax(output, dim=1))
            TC = np.diag(cm)
            cTC += np.sum(TC)
        return cTC, loss , np.sum(cm)
```

output/y shape before squeeze: ([101705, 11])

output/y shape after squeeze: ([101705, 11])

Comment: Are you referring to [`np.squeeze`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html)? If so, a) you are not using it anywhere in your code, b) what were you expecting it to do?

Comment: Oh sorry, I accidentally posted old code snippet. Edited.

Comment: Again, what are you expecting it to do? `squeeze` removes dimensions of size 1. If you try to use it on an axis of size bigger than 1, it gives an error. What are the starting shapes of your arrays and what do you want the end result to be?

Comment: The dimensions don't change ever after running squeeze on them. The starting shapes are: ([101705, 11]), and the shapes after squeeze: ([101705, 11]). How is this possible?

Comment: Of course they dont change, none of them are singleton dimensions. I.e. none of them have size 1. Have you read the documentation in the link I posted?